# How to implement a RESTful api to existing apache hosted cgi applications?

Tags: apache, rest, cgi

I have been asked to implement a RESTful API to call the functions of a legacy web application.

```
            web server           application server
           ┌─────────────┐      ┌─────────────┐
           │apache       │      │apache       │
           │httpd        │      │httpd        │
           │             │      │             │
request    │  ┌──────────┴─┐    │ ┌───────────┴─┐    ┌─────────────┐
─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─│─ ┼ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─│─ ─ ┼ ┼ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┼ ─ ▶│ c++         │
           │  │ mod_proxy  │    │ │  mod_fcgid  │    │ application │
◀ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─│─ ┼ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─│─ ─ ┼ ┼ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┼ ─ ─│             │
response   │  └──────────┬─┘    │ └───────────┬─┘    └─────────────┘
           └─────────────┘      └─────────────┘
```

Requests to the application are made to apache web servers which reverse proxy the requests to application servers running fast cgi which call the c++ applications.

If the request is a POST the c++ applications expect to receive parameters in the request body.
If the request is a GET the c++ applications expect to receive parameters in the query string.

The applications do not inspect the query string if the request is a POST.

I would like to be able to map requests to rest style URLs to the request pattern expected by the old applications

eg

```
/api/animal/tiger/feed/biscuit
```

would map to

```
/feeder.exe?animal=tiger&feed=biscuit
```

This is achievable, but clumsy, using mod_rewrite when the request is a GET, but I do not think mod_rewrite can modify POST parameters.
It may be achievable using mod_security but I'm not certain that is a good approach.

What techniques or apache extensions are available to assist with this?

Comment: The company is historically disposed against using php and java,
and would be reluctant to implement a solution that involves a new server (such as nginx or node), however it may not be viable to implement an apache only solution.

Comment: This question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916780/apache-module-for-restful-services
discussed writing an apache module. I am inclined to think the complexity of writing and maintaining a module is not a good idea. The question does mention using python bindings to call cgi